# Implementing SMS "Share my current location" in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, mobile, sms, google-maps-android-api-2

In the messaging app on my android phone, I can share my location. When I share my location, it appears as a text message with a little map preview. The map preview is not a full, embedded map, i.e. you can't interact with it etc. If you click on it, it then opens the actual google maps app. Multiple location previews can appear in a single conversation. I want to implement the same thing in flutter, however I can only find how to implement a full in-app map, which is not what I want. Is there a way to do this map preview in flutter?